# Read specific columns in a text file

Tags: c#, file, text, multiple-columns

I have a text file at the location C:\Users\Volki\Documents\Ciel\Members\Cielmember.txt.
The text file content is 2 Lines, it looks like this:
code1=EX386MF06BR
code2=DB45ZE45GT5

What I'm looking for is to ignore what is before the Character "=" (code1/code2) then start reading columns (Column by column) in each line, and display every column value in Console.WriteLine().

Here is what I've tried but it doesn't work.

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Volki\Desktop\Test\testX.txt"))
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@filename);
    for (int y = 0; y < lines.Length; y++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(lines[y]);
        string[] columns = lines[y].Split('\t');
        for (int z = 0; z < columns.Length; z++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(z + ":" + columns[z]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you are using `split` to split the files in new lines, why not use the same technique to split each line by `=`? Then access the second element: `split(columns[z], '=')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try splitting lines based on “=“

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Volki\Desktop\Test\testX.txt"))
{
       string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@filename);
        for (int y = 0; y < lines.Length; y++)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(lines[y]);
                 string[] columns = lines[y].Split('=');
                // Columns should have two entries, one for codeX and another one for value. Since you only need the latter, print the second entry in columns 
                Console.WriteLine(columns[1]);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: i think i didn't ask the correct question. what i want is Character by Character not Column by Column,